# Empty attachment using PHP mailer

Tags: php

I am trying to send a mail with a attachment using PHP. When I send the mail I am recieving it with a empty attachment (the attachment file size = 0 bytes). The filepath that I am using is correct.

Does someone know what is wrong with my script. Why am I recieving an empty attachment?

Here is my script:

```
    $to = $destination; 
    $from = 'test@test.test'; 
    $fromName = 'Test'; 
    $subject = $subject;
    $file = "./image-based-pdf-sample.pdf";
    $htmlContent = $content; 
     
    $headers = "From: $fromName"." <".$from.">"; 
     
    $semi_rand = md5(time());  
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";  
     
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 
     
    $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" . 
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n" . $htmlContent . "\r\n";  
     
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n"; 
    $fp =    @fopen($file,"rb"); 
    $data =  @fread($fp,filesize($file)); 
     
    @fclose($fp); 
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data)); 
    $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($file)."\"\n" .  
    "Content-Description: ".basename($file)."\n" . 
    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($file)."\"; size=".filesize($file).";\n" .  
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n" . $data . "\r\n"; 

    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--"; 
    $returnpath = "-f" . $from; 
     
    $mail = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $returnpath);  
     
    echo $mail?"<h1>Success</h1>":"<h1>Error</h1>";
```

Comment: **(1)** I have tested your code (I removed the closing `}` at the end which is redundant) -- the attachment is 100% **fine** and I can receive the pdf attachment in the mail and can open it without problem (but I have tested it by using a small size pdf). Can you use a small size pdf "name.pdf" and re-try to see the result  ? **(2)** By the way, it is a standard to use \r\n instead of \n\n , but my server is fine with \n\n too, but you may wish to adhere to the standard and change all \n\n to \r\n. Thanks

Comment: @KenLee I just tried it with a small pdf. The result is still the same. I also changed all \n\n to \r\n. Still no difference

Comment: I have added an example PDF file to the question. I am trying to send a image-based-pdf file.

Comment: Hi, you are using `$file = "https://nlsblog.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/image-based-pdf-sample.pdf";` , please change to use a local file instead (e.g.  $file = "./xxxx.pdf";)

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I am using a local file. `https://nlsblog.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/image-based-pdf-sample.pdf` was just a example. I changed my first post.

Comment: RFC1341 specifically mention CRLF (i.e., `\r\n`) as line separator. So I would expect you to have a blank line (i.e., _two_ CRLF sequences) between headers and body: `"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n" . $data . "\r\n";`

Comment: _"Does someone know what is wrong with my script."_ - the whole attempt of trying to assemble a multipart mail yourself, of course ... Use an existing, established mailer library such as PHPMailer, instead of trying to deal with the complexities of a multipart mail body yourself.